# how to store multiple unique values for a single key within a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a file which has multiple columns

i.e. IP(at column0),ID(at column2).

I would like to compare this two column and would like to get the result as IP vs corresponding unique IDs by rowwise

i.e. (IP : id1, id2, id3...)

I am getting the results but not in row wise rather sequentially. Further, for some IPs I am getting same values repeating time and again                  i.e. (IP : id1, id2, id3, id1, id2, id3,id1, id2, id3...).

Sample file :

```
    ip, date,id,num1,num2
    1xx.100.119.114,2018-09-           09T12:00:00+0900,05b8a163c1e482227fddcfcf2ef9d0f1,0,1
    1xx.103.183.254,2018-08-  20T02:44:00+0900,07ed70b09b70b13ba08236ccb88f44a8,1,0
    1xx.107.19.222,2018-08-22T05:08:00+0900,d5d673f8ee6b3fe1b8f796e0abdad96d,1,0
    1xx.109.69.211,2018-08-10T18:55:00+0900,6a751d871f54ab01a72ef3edd07cb8d4,1,0
    1xx.111.249.236,2018-09-15T04:03:00+0900,a5ec6954f3a7bf8bbc9e2077c24075ca,0,0
    1xx.116.117.193,2018-09-29T13:45:00+0900,aec55760152a450d9aac31046a5b0677,1,0
    1xx.119.4.181,2018-08-22T04:38:00+0900,-,-,-
```

I first start doing by for loop and pieces the line into pieces of string. then compare the ID with IP and stored in default dictionary if matches the criteria.

```py
    import json
    import re
    from collections import defaultdict
    from collections import Counter
    import collections

    # making the list of lines from the text file
    f1_lines=[]
    with open("clust1vsSoftbankUID.txt") as f1:
        f1_lines=f1.readlines()

    # storing IP vs UID in dict format

    d = defaultdict(list)      
    for ln1 in f1_lines:
        pieces1=ln1.split(",")
        for ln2 in f1_lines:
                pieces2=ln2.split(",")
                if pieces2[2] == pieces1[2]:
                        d[pieces2[2]].append(pieces2[0])
    print(d)
```

Actual result is:

```
'4a862bad794926595a85d3bde74f0de2': ['1xx.87.43.12','1xx.87.46.95', '1xx.87.48.107', '1xx.87.48.216', '1xx.87.50.70', '1xx.87.43.12', '1xx.87.46.95', '1xx.87.48.107', '1xx.87.48.216', '1xx.87.50.70', '1xx.87.43.12', '1xx.87.46.95', '1xx.87.48.107', '1xx.87.48.216', '1xx.87.50.70', '1xx.87.43.12', '1xx.87.46.95', '1xx.87.48.107', '1xx.87.48.216', '1xx.87.50.70', '1xx.87.43.12', '1xx.87.46.95', '1xx.87.48.107', '1xx.87.48.216', '1xx.87.50.70']
```

Expected Result:

```
'4a862bad794926595a85d3bde74f0de2': ['1xx.87.43.12',  '1xx.87.46.95', '1xx.87.48.107', '1xx.87.48.216', '1xx.87.50.70', ]
```

So, There should not have repeating values of IP w.r.t key ID.

actually it should be like (IP : id1, id2, id3,...).

but I am getting as i.e. (IP : id1, id2, id3, id1, id2, id3,id1, id2, id3...)

secondly, the values I am getting is not displaying as row wise.I am expecting to get in rowwise like

```
'4a862bad794926595a85d3bde74f0de2': 
'1xx.87.43.12',        
'1xx.87.46.95', 
'1xx.87.48.107', 
'1xx.87.48.216', 
'1xx.87.50.70',
```

Comment: Is the file a csv ?

Comment: No, its .txt file

Comment: It looks like a csv `comma separated values` file, check again!

Comment: Yes the values are separated by comma within the file. But the file name extension is .txt  i.e clust1vsSoftbankUID.txt. By seeing the file extension, I guessed this is a .txt file.